# Prolog : Iterating over a list and creating a predicate

Tags: prolog

I'm creating a predicate `enum` that takes a list and a number for example `[1,2,3,4]` and `3` and returns a list that contains lists of length 3 made out of the list introduced. So in the example given `enum([1,2,3,4],3,[[1,2,3],[2,3,4]])`.
I've created a function take that takes only the first list of length N but I get errors when I try to loop it to get all of the others. Thanks you for helping.

```
append([],L,L).
append([H|T],L2,[H|L3]):- append(T,L2,L3).

len([],0).
len([_|B],X):- len(B,X1), X is X1+1.

take(_,X,Y) :- X =< 0, !, X =:= 0, Y = [].
take([],_,[]).
take([A|B],X,[A|C]):- Z is X-1, take(B,Z,C).

enum([],_,[]).
enum([N1|N2],N3,N4):-
   len([N1|N2],U),
   N3=<U,
   take([N1|N2],N3,T1),
   append([N4],[T1],T2),
   !,
   enum(N2,N3,T2).
```

Answer (score 0):

I will focus on the `take/3` predicate, which is the core of your question. In order to get a sublist like `[2,3,4]` of `[1,2,3,4]`, you have to be able to skip the first element and just take a sublist of the rest.

You can achieve this by adding this clause to your definition:

```
take([_|Xs], N, Ys) :- take(Xs, N, Ys).
```

With this you now get several different sublists of length 3, but also some other superfluous solutions:

```
?- take([1,2,3,4], 3, Xs).
Xs = [1, 2, 3] ;
Xs = [1, 2, 4] ;
Xs = [1, 2] ;
Xs = [1, 3, 4] ;
Xs = [1, 3] ;
Xs = [1, 4] ;
Xs = [1]  % etc.
```

This is because your clause `take([], _, [])` accepts an empty list as a "sublist of any length" of an empty list. I think you only wanted to accept the empty list as a sublist of length 0. If you remove this clause, your first clause will enforce that, and you only get solutions of length exactly 3:

```
?- take([1,2,3,4], 3, Xs).
Xs = [1, 2, 3] ;
Xs = [1, 2, 4] ;
Xs = [1, 3, 4] ;
Xs = [2, 3, 4] ;
false.
```

As a side note, your first clause is fine as is, but it can be simplified a bit to:

```
take(_,X,Y) :- X = 0, !, Y = [].
```

I would also advise you to use more readable variable names. For numbers like list lengths, we often use `N`. For lists, it's customary to use names like `Xs`, `Ys`, etc., with `X`, `Y`, etc. for members of the corresponding list.

Finally, to find all solutions of a predicate, you need to use a system predicate like `setof`, `bagof`, or `findall`. There is no way to write your `enum` in pure Prolog.

Comment: I have the feeling that this is about a sliding window, not about all subsequences of a given length. This is just from reading the example, I don't think this is explicitly defined in the question as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

Because I am not sure about the advice in the other answer, here is my take on your problem.

First, don't define your own `append/3` and `length/2`, `append/3` is by now Prolog folklore, you can find it in [textbooks 30 years old](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/art-prolog). And `length/2` is really difficult to get right on your own, use the built-in.

Now: to take the first `N` elements at the front of a list `L`, you can say:

```
length(Front, N),
append(Front, _, L)
```

You create a list of the length you need, then use `append/3` to split off this the front from the list you have.

With this in mind, it would be enough to define a predicate `sliding_window/3`:

```
sliding_window(L, N, [L]) :-
        length(L, N).
sliding_window(L, N, [W|Ws]) :-
        W = [_|_], % W should be at least one long
        length(W, N),
        append(W, _, L),
        L = [_|L0],
        sliding_window(L0, N, Ws).
```

This kind of works, but it will loop after giving you all useful answers:

```
?- sliding_window([a,b], N, Ws).
N = 2,
Ws = [[a, b]] ;
N = 1,
Ws = [[a], [b]] ;
% loops
```

It loops because of the same little snippet:

```
length(Front, N),
append(Front, _, L)
```

With `length/2`, you keep on generating lists of increasing length; once `Front` is longer than `L`, the `append/3` fails, `length/2` makes an even longer list, and so on forever.

One way out of this would be to use `between/3` to constrain the length of the front. If you put it in its own predicate:

```
front_n(L, N, F) :-
        length(L, Max),
        between(1, Max, N),
        length(F, N),
        append(F, _, L).
```

With this:

```
sliding_window(L, N, [L]) :-
        length(L, N).
sliding_window(L, N, [W|Ws]) :-
        front_n(L, N, W),
        L = [_|L0],
        sliding_window(L0, N, Ws).
```

And now it finally works:

```
?- sliding_window([a,b,c,d], 3, Ws).
Ws = [[a, b, c], [b, c, d]] ;
false.

?- sliding_window([a,b,c], N, Ws).
N = 3,
Ws = [[a, b, c]] ;
N = 1,
Ws = [[a], [b], [c]] ;
N = 2,
Ws = [[a, b], [b, c]] ;
false.
```

*Exercise*: get rid of the harmless, but unnecessary choice point.